# Join two tables on multiple conditions Using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a 2 Tables with below structures

**Table 1**-- Containing Values like this.

| OTHER_CODE | CAPACITY_CODE | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 |  |
| A | 5 |  |
| A | 9 |  |
| A | (null) |  |
| B | 2 |  |
| B | 6 |  |
| B | 2 |  |

**Table_2**- With Values Like

| OTHER_CODE | CAPACITY_CODE | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | A |
| A | 5 | B |
| A | (null) | C |
| A | ELSE | D |
| B | ALL | E |
| (null) | ALL | F |

I need to Join **Table_1** *with* **Table_2** on basis of columns ***OTHERCODE** and **CAPACITYCODE** and update values in Column **Result** of  **Table*****1 **using a Merge statement.

I need to handle and match Values based on ELSE and ALL values too.

1. Check for Direct Match
2. Check if ALL or ELSE condition

The Final **TABLE_1** must look like

| OTHER_CODE | CAPACITY_CODE | Result | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | A | Direct Join |
| A | 5 | B | Direct Join |
| A | 9 | D | Satsifying ELSE condition |
| A | (null) | C | Direct join with NVL handling |
| B | 2 | E | As Value for Capacity*Code in Table*B is ALL |
| B | 6 | E | As Value for CapacityCode in TableB is ALL |
| B | 2 | E | As Value for CapacityCode in TableB is ALL |

I Tried Joining both the tables but the was unable to satisfy Else and ALL conditions. Hope if someone can help me on this.

There are Several **Result ** Columns like , Result 1 ,2 in both tables which needs to be updated using the same logic.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

here is a fiddle to work on https://dbfiddle.uk/FMKdWzQT

I got the query working.  by using a case statement and assigning a number so I could use max then I just remove the number.

```
SELECT a.other_code,
       a.capacity_code,
       (
              SELECT SUBSTR(max(
                     CASE WHEN b.other_code = a.other_code AND  a.capacity_code = b.capacity_code THEN  concat('3',b.myresult)
                          WHEN b.other_code = a.other_code AND  a.capacity_code is null and  b.capacity_code is null THEN  concat('2',b.myresult)
                          WHEN b.other_code = a.other_code  AND b.capacity_code in ('ELSE', 'ALL') THEN  concat('1',b.myresult)
                          else null end),2) 
                          
              FROM   table2 b ) as myresult
FROM   table1 a
```

however I can not get the update to work. I tried a merge it is give me the unstable row error and I tried an update select but that is giving me single row subquery error so maybe someone else can take a look at the fiddle.  here was my attempt at the update.

```
 UPDATE table1
SET myresult = (
  SELECT myresult
  FROM (
  SELECT a.other_code,
       a.capacity_code,
       (
              SELECT SUBSTR(max(
                     CASE WHEN b.other_code = a.other_code AND  a.capacity_code = b.capacity_code THEN  concat('3',b.myresult)
                          WHEN b.other_code = a.other_code AND  a.capacity_code is null and  b.capacity_code is null THEN  concat('2',b.myresult)
                          WHEN b.other_code = a.other_code  AND b.capacity_code in ('ELSE', 'ALL') THEN  concat('1',b.myresult)
                          else null end),2) 
                          
              FROM   table2 b ) as myresult
FROM   table1 a
  )t2
  WHERE table1.other_code = t2.other_code and nvl(table1.capacity_code,'x') = nvl(t2.capacity_code,'x')
);
```

Comment: Bryan Dellinger
to avoid single row subquery error just put at the end of the where clause in the update statement 
WHERE table1.other_code = t2.other_code and nvl(table1.capacity_code,'x') = nvl(t2.capacity_code,'x') 
Fetch first 1 row only );
and it wil work and update the table.
Hope it help